# Column (and Grid) Alignment Changes with OpenerView

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment, column

`Column` does not maintain `Alignment` settings when `OpenerView` opens and closes.

```
Column[{Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .25}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Small],
  Sequence @@ ConstantArray[
    OpenerView[{"Text and Stuff wider than the graphic",
      "Wide grid of numbers and a lot of stuff and the like."}, False],
    3]},
 Alignment -> {{Center, {Left}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

The above `Column` displays as expected.  The first row is centred and the remaining rows are aligned to the left.  However, look at what happens if I open a one of the `OpenerView` items.

[image]

The rows that should be aligned to the left change their alignment to centre. The behaviour is:

- All `OpenerView`s closed then they are correctly aligned to the left.
- Any `OpenerView` open is aligned to the left but those closed are aligned center.

Have I spec'd `Alignment` incorrectly or is this a bug?

---

Adding that the same happens with `Grid`.

```
Grid[{{Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .25}]}, 
    ImageSize -> Small]},
  Sequence @@ ConstantArray[
    OpenerView[{"Text and Stuff wider than the graphic",
      "Wide grid of numbers and a lot of stuff and the like."}, False],
    {3, 1}]},
 Alignment -> {{Center, {Left}}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Try `OpenerView[..., ImageSize->All]`. Then it won't jump around.

Comment: @JackLaVigne That was the ticket. I need to use `ImageSize -> {All, Automatic}` instead of just `ImageSize -> All` as the hidden grid is tall. Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that for `OpenerView` the option `ImageSize -> Automatic` instructs it to only leave space for the expressions that are in view.

With `ImageSize -> All` it will leave space for the largest expression.

```
Column[{
  Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .25}]}, ImageSize -> Small],
  Sequence @@ ConstantArray[
    OpenerView[{
      "Text and Stuff wider than the graphic",
      "Wide grid of numbers and a lot of stuff and the like."
      },
     False,
     ImageSize -> All],
    3
    ]},
 Alignment -> {{Center, {Left}}, Automatic}
 ]
```

This gives a column that looks like this with the first element open:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to control the width and height independently you can use:

```
Grid[{
  {Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .25}]}, ImageSize -> Small]},
  Sequence @@ ConstantArray[
    OpenerView[
     {
      "Text and Stuff wider than the graphic", 
      "Wide grid of numbers and a lot of stuff and the like."
      },
     False,
     ImageSize -> {All, Automatic}
     ],
    {3, 1}
    ]},
 Alignment -> {{Center, {Left}}, Automatic}
 ]
```

Here the width is the width of the maximum width of all of the components but the height will only display what is required to display what is on the screen.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This helped.  I've gone with `ImageSize -> {All, Automatic}` instead as the hidden grid is very tall.